# itel phone unable to switch on

Tags: boot

I bought a new itel phone yesterday. I charged it a bit then added apps and photos and music. I played some music during the night. I tried rebooting does not go on, it vibrates but screen is blank.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said,

> played some music during the night

Its most probable that your phone is out of battery juice, given that it must have been drained overnight. That's why you're only able to get a vibration and a quick blink on the screen and nothing more.

So charge your phone mate, and you're good to go